# Magento Search Product

Tags: php, magento, search

When I try to search a product in magento, it shows incorrect price

Please check the image url:

http://content.screencast.com/users/Japhz03/folders/Default/media/ab92d2ad-da1a-4be0-989e-c25edcf80bdf/Price.JPG

The price for the 'Izmir Sisal Rug' is must $39.00 - $1,299.00.
But when I'll search the product, all product price went wrong. It display $12.00 - $92.00

What is wrong with this?

Comment: Do you use any module that affects the product or the price ?

Comment: I didn't use anything.. the last time this was okay.

Comment: did you regenerate the product search index ? flush cache ?

Comment: How do I regenerate the product search index? What I did is, I just flush caches.

Kindly look at this img link: http://content.screencast.com/users/Japhz03/folders/Default/media/f685fcdc-a152-4b41-9465-3e5e04fde986/Search_results_for_sisal_-_2014-07-10_17.53.07.png

it shows the same prices. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: I think I already did also regenerating the product search index, by going to index management, and reindex all the data, Still the same.

Comment: I think you have module that interfer or an hosting level cache. In your admin, the prices are ok ? Is the website online ?

Comment: Yes, the prices are okay. the website is online..

Comment: can you give us the address, it will permit to check for any other dysfunctionments.

Comment: www.naturalhomerugs.com, and try to search 'Sisal'

Answer (score 0):

The problem most probably comes from your configurable products. The visibility is not set correctly and you have differences between search and categories. You need to set that the simple product are not visible individualy and can not be found throught the research.

EG :

http://www.naturalhomerugs.com/izmir-sisal-rug.html (12$-92$) in the product page

http://www.naturalhomerugs.com/izmir-sisal.html (doesn't work on ff)

http://www.naturalhomerugs.com/catalogsearch/advanced/result/?material=483 (displays prices as you say but izmir appears twice)

http://www.naturalhomerugs.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=%27sisal%27 (izmir appears twice as well but with the prices that can be found on the product page of the first link)

Then you need to regenerate indexes and flush the cache.